# Is it possible to log/monitor Bluetooth errors?

Tags: bluetooth, error-handling

My Bluetooth keyboard stops working after I wake up the computer from suspension, for no apparent reason ([Cannot write with bluetooth keyboard after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218706/after-suspension-cant-write-with-bluetooth-keyboard)).

So I believe an error is being silently output.

I am wondering if there is a way to monitor Bluetooth errors, possibly in the terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/var/log/syslog
```

will have notices regarding bluetooth.

```
grep blue /var/log/syslog.1|more
```

shows amongst others ...

```
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Failed to init time plugin
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Failed to init alert plugin
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Mar 12 17:47:36 schijfwereld bluetoothd[894]: Bluetooth Management interface ini
tialized
Mar 12 18:38:23 schijfwereld bluetoothd[862]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
```

If you do a

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

and enable/disble bluetooth it will start listing commands when they are inserted into syslog so you can monitor this file in real time.